# Reduce wireframe opacity in the Weight Paint mode

Tags: interface, weight-painting

When I enable Wireframe in the Screen Overlay TAB there is an Opacity option, but it does not affect the wireframe on the selected mesh for weight painting for some reason, it just makes it look less orange. Is there a way to reduce the opacity of this wireframe?

I'm using Blender 4.0

[image]

[image]